# Spring iceFaces integration questions

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, icefaces, spring-webflow

i intend to use IceFaces with spring framework
and i have some questions, before going to this process:

1. Is it possible to use it with spring-mvc ?
2. If it's possible to use it with spring-mvc, what's better mvc or webflow ?
3. Can i use spring controllers as beans instead of the JSF managed beans ?
4. How the binding process is done, through spring binding or another way ?

please advise, if there are suggested links it will be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mix spring with JSF easily for bean management. In such scenario spring can entirely replace JSF managed beans support and you will be able to address spring beans directly from your EL expressions in xhtml pages. The mechanism is described in spring documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html#jsf

I don't think adding spring-mvc or spring-webflow to this mix makes much sense. JSF relies on its own servlet. You may use spring servlets for some side tasks like generating documents or specific views which can't be rendered by JSF but I'm not sure your project will really need that. For basic usage JSF is exclusive with spring-mvc/spring-webflow.

Comment: following url is about integrating webflow with icefaces: http://www.icefaces.org/docs/v1_7_2/htmlguide/devguide/AdvancedTopics11.html

Comment: I am not sure what would you gain from such integration but perhaphs someone tried it and will share his experience.